# Powershell add suffix to filenames, based on prefix

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that consists of a number of text files that have been named:

```
1Customer.txt
2Customer.txt
...
99Customer.txt
```

I am trying to create powershell script that will rename the files to a more logical:

```
Customer1.txt
Customer2.txt
...
Customer99.txt
```

The prefix can be anything from 1 digit to 3 digits.

As I am new to powershell, I really don't know how I can achieve this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The most straigth forward way is a gci/ls/dir
- with a where matching only BaseNames starting with a number with a
  RegEx and piping to
- Rename-Item and building the new name from submatches.

---

```
ls |? BaseName -match '^(\d+)([^0-9].*)$' |ren -new {"{0}{1}{2}" -f $matches[2],$matches[1],$_.extension}
```

The same code without aliases

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Obect {$_.BaseName -match '^(\d+)([^0-9].*)$'} |
    Rename-Item -NewName {"{0}{1}{2}" -f $matches[2],$matches[1],$_.extension}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem .\Docs -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Name -match "^(?<Number>\d+)(?<Type>\w+)\.\w+$")
        {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($matches.Type)$($matches.Number)$($_.Extension)"
        }
    }
```

The line:

```
$_.Name -match "^(?<Number>\d+)(?<Type>\w+)\.\w+$")
```

takes the file name (e.g. '23Suppliers.txt') and perform a pattern match on it, pulling out the number part (23) and the 'type' part ('Suppliers'), naming them 'Number' and 'Type' respectively.  These are stored by PowerShell in its automatic variable `$matches`, which is used when working with regular expressions.

We then reconstruct the new file using details from the original file, such as the file's extension (`$_.Extension`) and the matched type (`$matches.Type`) and number (`$matches.Number`):

```
"$($matches.Type)$($matches.Number)$($_.Extension)"
```

Comment: Great. As there are a large number of other file types (eg.Suppliers, Addresses, SalesOrders) how can I make this pick up any file that has a number prefix? Thanks.

Comment: This will work as it stands for any filename in the format `<number><type>.txt`.  For example, all of these will work: `1Customer.txt`, `23Suppliers.txt`, `99Addresses.txt`, etc.  Only a slight modification is needed to handle different file extensions.

Comment: That's great, but I have over 100 different file types. Can it be done as a wildcard for the <type>?  Thanks.

Comment: @Bandito you can match against BaseName and then add the extension back on when it's renamed. Update these `if($_.BaseName -match "^(?<Number>\d+)(?<Suffix>\w+)")` and `Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Directory)\$($matches.Suffix)$($matches.Number)$($_.Extension)"`

Comment: @Bandito, I updated my example to make it work with different file extensions.

Comment: On a rename the `$_.Directory` part isn't neccessary.

Comment: @LotPings.  Good spot.  Amended accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a nicer way to do this with regex, but the following is a quick first go at it:

```
$prefix = "Customer"
Get-ChildItem C:\folder\*$prefix.txt  | Rename-Item -NewName {$prefix + ($_.Name -replace $prefix,'')}
```